# Query ravendb without defining a model class?

Tags: c#, ravendb

Is there a way to query ravendb without defining a model class? Normally we define model and issues query like this:

```
public class Site
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string URL { get; set; }
   public string Notes { get; set; }
}

var documentStore = new Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore{Url = "http://localhost:8080" };
 documentStore.Initialize();
 using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
 {
    var sites = session.Query<Site>()
                   .Where(x => x.Title.StartsWith("CN")).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < sites.Count; i++)   {
         MessageBox.Show(sites[i].Title + " - " + sites[i].URL);
    }  
 }
```

But can I query like I can for SQL server - without defining table structure which I may not even know? In the above example, I need to declare a class `Site` to be able run a query: `var sites = session.Query<Site>()`. I'd like to run this like `session.Query<"Site">()`

Is this even possible?  How can I set up this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use database commands (`Query`) to accomplish what you are trying, as long as you know the name of the document collection you are trying to get. See [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/advanced/full-query-syntax) for more information.

```
QueryResult sites = store.DatabaseCommands.Query(
    "Sites/ByTitle",
    new IndexQuery
        {
            Query = "Title:CN*"
        }, null);
```

Comment: trying to test this but not sure in which assembly Query methods resides. It shows me as undefined methods and I have all ravendb client inlcudes from nuget.